# Has the Michelson-Morley experiment been done in space?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, experimental-physics, speed-of-light

Has the [Michelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) been done in space?  I mean that exact experiment I realize GPS and similar technologies are doing a similar thing.  Are any measuring the literal exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

> I mean that exact experiment

Well, ”exact” is a little excessive. The exact experimental apparatus is on the ground at Case Western Reserve University, and nobody will be burning an argand lamp in space, so if you want to go that far for "exact", then no.

However, Michelson interferometers in general have a reasonably wide range of applications in space and several Michelson interferometers have been built and launched into orbit on satellites. They are useful for observations of actual wind at sub-orbital altitudes and observations of the sun etc. at orbital altitudes. See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer#Atmospheric_and_space_applications