# All Michelson-Morley experiments have only been done in non-inertial conditions. Does special relativity apply or not?

Tags: symmetry, speed-of-light, aether

As far as I know not a single Michelson-Morley experiment has been done in non-inertial conditions. Shouldn't it be general relativity that applies to Michelson-Morley experiments done so far?

Comment: Have you compared a non-relativistic Newtonian vs a GR treatment of physics on the surface of the Earth?

Comment: @JonCuster or: How much does a laser beam fall when crossing a laser table in the lab?

Answer (score 1):

Special relativity is not limited to inertial frames nor to inertial objects. General relativity is only needed in the presence of significant tidal effects.

However, there are spaceborne interferometer experiments. So the premise of the question is not correct.

Comment: _"there are spaceborne interferometer experiments"_ I'm curious which ones you have in mind?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal see my answer here and the link therein https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/706943/has-the-michelson-morley-experiment-been-done-in-space

Comment: Michelson interferometer and Michelson-Morley experiment are *not* the same thing. More precisely what I mean is a Michelson interferometer apparatus and a Michelson-Morley experiment apparatus are not the same thing.

Comment: @mmx_in_orbit I clearly disagree